# Apk Easy Tool can't compile an apk after decompiling it

Tags: android, apk, reverse-engineering, apktool

I was using apk easy tool and it was working great, i was decompiling and compiling some of my apps, but suddenly when i compile an apk do some changes on the codes and when i try to compile it a pop up problem shows up and tells me to check the log and here's what i find

```
I: Using Apktool 2.4.0
I: Smaling smali folder into classes.dex...
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[1,11] Error for input '.zoozoo': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[1,18] Error for input '.filter': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[1,25] Error for input '/': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[1,7] mismatched input 'Lcom' expecting CLASS_DESCRIPTOR
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[1,40] Error for input ';': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[11,16] Error for input '.zoozoo': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[11,23] Error for input '.filter': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[11,30] Error for input '/': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[11,31] no viable alternative at input 'BaseActivity'
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[11,43] Error for input ';': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[11,31] missing EQUAL at 'BaseActivity'
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[11,44] mismatched input '->' expecting EQUAL
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[11,63] missing EQUAL at '('
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[21,30] no viable alternative at input 'Lcom'
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[21,34] Error for input '.zoozoo': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[21,41] Error for input '.filter': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[21,48] Error for input '/': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[21,61] Error for input ';': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[29,27] no viable alternative at input 'Lcom'
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[29,31] Error for input '.zoozoo': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[29,38] Error for input '.filter': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[29,45] Error for input '/': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[29,58] Error for input ';': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[33,28] Error for input '.zoozoo': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[33,35] Error for input '.filter': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[33,42] Error for input '/': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[33,57] Error for input ';': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[33,43] mismatched input 'BaseActivity$1' expecting COLON
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[33,71] Error for input '.zoozoo': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[33,78] Error for input '.filter': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[33,85] Error for input '/': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[33,98] Error for input ';': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[33,86] mismatched input 'BaseActivity' expecting END_METHOD_DIRECTIVE
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[35,28] Error for input '.zoozoo': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[35,35] Error for input '.filter': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[35,42] Error for input '/': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[35,57] Error for input ';': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[37,21] Error for input '.zoozoo': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[37,28] Error for input '.filter': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[37,35] Error for input '/': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[37,50] Error for input ';': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[50,28] Error for input '.zoozoo': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[50,35] Error for input '.filter': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[50,42] Error for input '/': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[50,57] Error for input ';': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[50,43] mismatched input 'BaseActivity$1' expecting COLON
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[50,71] Error for input '.zoozoo': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[50,78] Error for input '.filter': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[50,85] Error for input '/': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[50,98] Error for input ';': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[50,86] mismatched input 'BaseActivity' expecting END_METHOD_DIRECTIVE
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[56,28] Error for input '.zoozoo': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[56,35] Error for input '.filter': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[56,42] Error for input '/': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[56,57] Error for input ';': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[62,21] Error for input '.zoozoo': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[62,28] Error for input '.filter': Invalid directive
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[62,35] Error for input '/': Invalid text
..\1-Decompiled APKs\galaxy\smali\com\zoozoo\filter\BaseActivity$1.smali[62,50] Error for input ';': Invalid text
Could not smali file: com/zoozoo/filter/BaseActivity$1.smali
```